# Error when creating symbolic links

Tags: symlink

I'm trying to create a symlink but `ln` says it exist. I cannot see it in FTP and the `cd` gives me an error.

```
[root@vps82008 addons]# ln -s /root/sendsms/app/addons/sendsms /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms’: File exists
[root@vps82008 addons]# cd /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms
-bash: cd: /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis: `/var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms` is a symlink with nonexistent target.

`cd` says `No such file or directory` because the *target* doesn't exist. Still the symlink *itself* does exist, that's why `ln` says `File exists`. I guess maybe your FTP server is configured to ignore invalid or all symlinks.

Run the following command to confirm the hypothesis:

```
ls -ld /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms
```

If the symlink exists, just remove it before you proceed with `ln -s …` to create it anew (with a proper target this time); or use `ln -s -f …` to make `ln` overwrite it without complaining.

Warning: Removing or overwriting something else than a symlink may cause data loss. Removing or overwriting a symlink discards information what its target was. Make sure you know what the file really is. Aside from the above `ls -ld …` command, use `file` (if available):

```
file /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms
```

This tool should explicitly tell you the link is broken, if this is the case.

---

My attempt to replicate the problem:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test608752
$ cd /tmp/test608752
$ ls
$ ln -s foo bar
$ ln -s /tmp bar
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'bar': File exists
$ cd bar
-bash: cd: bar: No such file or directory
$ ls -ld bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kamil kamil 3 Sep 10 12:04 bar -> foo
$
```

Comment: this is the output lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 10 08:30 /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms -> /root/sendsms_module/app/addons/sendsms

Comment: @RaduCatalin Exactly. And I guess `/root/sendsms_module/app/addons/sendsms` does not exist. Please confirm.

Comment: I cannot see it in my ftp. But if I type ls -a I see it but with a red color instead of a blue one like the other folders

Comment: @RaduCatalin Can you use `file`? `file /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com/public_html/app/addons/sendsms` will explicitly tell you the link is broken, if this is the case.

Comment: Red color means the target of the link doesn't exist. So `/root/sendsms_module/app/addons/sendsms` does not exist.